# Can I avoid paying encoding/serialization costs when exchanging messages between two service applications?

Tags: java, serialization, encoding, binary

**TLDR; Is it practical for internal micro services to avoid serialization and talk to each other in binary to save on computational cost when sending messages? If so how would this work with JMS?**

When exchanging messages between machines on the internet we often use some form of encoding in to a format such as JSON. By doing this we ensure that two different machines with different binary formats as well as different default encodings can talk to each other.

As web developers this is reasonable, we have no idea what machines might be connecting to our services. However with the rise of micro services its not uncommon for applications within private networks such as Amazon's VPC to be communicating with each other. Given technologies such as cloud front we can be VERY exact about many details of our stack such as operating systems and software versions.

In such situations we do not have to allow for the same considerations that we would with a public services such as different operating systems and different encoding types.

At this point would it still be reasonable for these services to pay the computational costs of JSON encoding via HTTP? Would it be reasonable for a development team to pay the development overhead in introducing a serialization strategy to facilitate communication with a broaking technology? It would seem like we have an opportunity to simplify our stack as well as gain performance. Given this opportunity how would we exchange messages in this way? What would our Java code look like? Is this even practical to do?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, you'll need to narrow it down. Stackoverflow's format is not that of a discussion board but your question is written for that format. You can find more about formulating questions in the [help]. Note that " only ever communicate with each other in the exact same binary format" doesn't occur in the real world - message formats are constantly updates- how are you going to migrate your applications to a new format with this type of fixed binary format, especially if you want to not bring down your whole infrastructure for a rollout?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ErwinBolwidt . Fair enough. I will try and narrow this question down. I was on the fence about asking this because of that. In the interests of helping me do this before this question gets shot down can you give me a little more detail about why this does not occur in the real world? I have removed this part of the question BTW.

Comment: I haven't seen a case where a message doesn't evolve over time, even if it's small. You can still pick a binary format but it needs to be a bit more sophisticated then just the internal data structure - either versioning, or something with ignorable and optional parts of the data, or both, so that you can upgrade one side of a communication link before upgrading the other side.